# how to convert a mat converted dictionary(images) into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mat

[image: The image contains the output]
I have converted a mat file into python dictionary. Now how can i convert this into Pndas data frame.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use if need create dictionary of `DataFrames`:

```
d = {k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in matdata.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to flatten the arrays:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: v[0] for k,v in matdata.items()})
```

example:

```
matdata = {'a': np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]), 'b': np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])}

df = pd.DataFrame({k: v.ravel() for k,v in matdata.items()})
```

output:

```
   a   b
0  1   7
1  2   8
2  3   9
3  4  10
4  5  11
5  6  12
```

Comment: it says all arrays need to be same length. As the last array is one dimentional

Comment: @Shahed the output you expect is ambiguous, what would you like assuming `matdata = {'a': np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]), 'b': np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])}` as input?

Comment: Yes, but while trying to convert into df as you have mentioned it errors saying all arrays are not the same length

Comment: @ShahedIslam I understand, but to be able to help you, we need to know which output format you expect

Comment: exactly as you have showed , that's what I want as output

Comment: @Shahed what is the output of `{k: v.shape for k,v in matdata.items()}`?

Comment: the arrays are not of same length. This error I am getting